# How to conditionally insert a Map into a list in Java if the list does not already include a map containing a key value pair

Tags: java, arrays, list, hashmap, duplicates

I have a list of HashMap objects in Java.
I would like to conditionally add more HashMap objects to this list if the list does not already contain a HashMap having the same key value pair as in the new HashMap.

Here is an example HashMap list. Note that in reality, there are more keys. Here, I am just including "contact_id" for simplicity.

```
[{contact_id=16247115}, {contact_id=16247116}, {contact_id=16247117}, {contact_id=16247118}, {contact_id=16247119}]
```

Adding `{contact_id=16247117}` to this list should not be allowed.
Adding `{contact_id = 74857983}`, should be allowed.

Ideally, I would like to be able to conditionally add several HashMaps into this list in one line of code. If I were not to perform the conditional check, I could just use the syntax `listname.addAll(batchOfHashMaps)`. I'd like to do something similar, but precluding redundant HashMaps in the list.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this conditional insert in Java?

I reckon there must be a more efficient solution than evaluating each element in the list inside a for-loop.

Comment: You say that in reality the HashMap contains more keys, but you also say that you want to add a HashMap only if the list does not contain one with "the same key value pair".  Is your duplication checking strategy based on 2 HashMaps in the list having *no* key-value pairs in common, or just this one related to `contact_id`?

Comment: If all mappings must match, you can simply use a `HashSet`.

Comment: How exactly do you determine HashMap equality?

Comment: Like ajc2000 suggests, my duplication checking strategy is based on 2 HashMaps in the list having the same contact_id. The other keys can have different values.

Comment: @GNG. It sounds like you want a map or set, not a list. Is order relevant? If so, which order? Key or insertion?

Answer (score 2):

If you are only wanting to look at one key-value pair of the maps as an identifier, then you could use a Map instead of a List to hold everything.  For example,
Map<String, Map<String, String> mapOfMaps;

Then you could add one like:

```
mapOfMaps.putIfAbsent(mapToAdd.get("contact_id"), mapToAdd);
```

you could add multiple like:

```
batchOfHashMaps.forEach(m -> mapOfMaps.putIfAbsent(m.get("contact_id"), m));
```

To get a collection of your maps simply call values()

```
mapOfMaps.values();
```

Comment: You could use a set with a custom comparator